# Setting up a server with a NAS using a macbook pro 2011

Tags: linux-mint, webserver, nas

I am interested in setting up a server using my macbook pro (late 2011 with SSD and 16gb RAM). I have 2 major uses for this system:

1. I want to use the server as a computing environment, ideally to run analyses on, especially using R (hence selecting mint of all the distributions available). This environment would be accessible via an iPad where I might be able to edit code on the fly and run analyses using the mac's hardware from basically anywhere with internet.
2. I would like this system to also be running a NAS 24/7 to store data (mostly a large photo data base from lightroom). I don't need to be able to edit these photos directly from the NAS as it would probably be a horribly laggy experience anyway but to be able to move them to a local SSD on my editing computer when I want (and also move them from the SSD on a to the NAS HDD). This editing computer is not on the same network as my macbook pro.

Note: I have just bought the 10TB NAS seagate ironwolf HDD as the base storage for the NAS.

So I would like to know if this is firstly at all possible?

Secondly what might be the best linux mint server and NAS software to get the job done?

Thirdly how connection to the NAS and server would be facilitated and kept secure?

Thank you very much for your time in advance

Comment: What is the down vote for exactly? Perhaps I can fix it with some feedback?

Comment: If you're looking at storage for a NAS get two disks in a mirrored configuration (RAID1 or equivalent) and consider backups. Unless your data's not important, that is.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Does a NAS always need to have a RAID config? It is important but I will back up elsewhere until I can afford a second HDD of the same capacity. Is it possible to just set a single HDD as a RAID set up then progressively add to it or does one always need to start with clean disks?

Comment: A NAS doesn't _need_ a mirrored configuration, but you need to consider what happens when its single disk dies. In my book 10TB is a lot of data to lose.